# Why do my php error_log() statements get sent to the apache error.log?

Tags: apache, php

What I've tried:

php.ini

```
log_errors = On
error_log = /etc/httpd/logs/php_error.log
```

httpd.conf

```
php_value error_log /etc/httpd/logs/php_error.log
```

I've tried these in different combinations, stopped and started httpd and verified that these settings are recognized in phpinfo(), but it all still goes to the apache error.log file.

How can I get php error_log() output in a separate file from the httpd error.log file?

PHP 5.3.5
Server version: Apache/2.2.3

Thanks

Comment: Odd, as many was as I try this, I can't get it to work either.  SELinux disabled, no difference. Full or relative path in php.ini, no difference.  Making sure the file exists and is writable by apache - no difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ... The file should be writable by the web server's user ...

Source: http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-log

try to change the the log directory to e.g. `/var/log/php/my_php_errors.log`
make sure the folder exists:

```
mkdir /var/log/php/
```

`/etc/...` is usually used not for logging use some folder/file in `/var/log/...` instead

Comment: Doh, the file was owned by apache, but the parent directory was owned by root without read access for other users. The /etc path was just a soft link to /var/log/httpd, that's how CentOS has it set up by default.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you're using two different log paths?

```
error_log = /etc/httpd/logs/php_error.log
php_value error_log /etc/php/logs/php_error.log
                         ^^^^
```

Does /etc/php/logs exist?